# Are there any large scale enterprise frameworks for PHP

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm curious if there are any commonly used large enterprise frameworks for PHP that would be your whole or most of your environment if you were working in PHP. Something comparable to ASP.NET's WebForms or MVC in that when you're working in either one, most of your code and system is based off of working integratively within that framework.

Edit:
Specifically I'm looking for a framework that fit's the bill of basically being what you would use for 99% of your work in writing your website, this means:

- data retrieval, some kind of ORM in the framework
- data representation, some kind of data aware automatically configured UI controls that make reading and writing to a DB easy
- data caching
- data serialization
- data communication, an easy way to generate and host web services of various sorts

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Obligatory *roll-eyes*

Comment: Is there an affordable family van that has the performance of a Ferrari?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini yeah, it's just *really* unsafe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most used frameworks are:

- Zend Framework http://framework.zend.com/
- Symfony http://symfony.com/

Both have already a second version out there and a big community supporting them.

Edit: They support almost all your listed features:

- data retrieval
- - in ZF via Table Data Gateway Pattern
- - Symfony can integrate Doctrine, which is a full ORM
- Both are only frameworks and have no integrated admin frontend to edit the data, but provide easy-to-use formular and element classes, to set them up on your own
- Both have multiple ways to implement data caching, serialization and comunication

Comment: Do both of these act as a wrapper to your full stack so you're using them AJAX to SQL and everything between?

Comment: Yes, have a look at their websites and examples.

Comment: You're really supposed to summarize links you post, with supporting information backing up why they are relevant and how they answer a question. Link-only answers are low-quality as they really don't help people any more comprehensively than google. If you could summarize the info on those links in your answer, it would go a long way to making it helpful to people in the future.

Comment: I added some information to your requested points, but both are full stack frameworks and include hundreds of features. So to get a better look we either need more information about the application you want to develop or you have to look it up on your own.

Comment: Perfect, that bit of summary is all that's needed. When posting link-answers in the future, remember that you still need to give explanation of why whatever you linked answers the question being asked, doesn't take a lot of summarizing, just enough to answer the question at hand as your edit does. Thanks!